# How to force letters augmented with a mathematical symbol to be placed in an alphabetical order in the glossary?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature

I'm using the `nomentbl` package to generate a glossary of my symbols. This works great for most general cases.
I'm using a class file where commands are defined to include Latin and Greek symbols as follows:

```
% Latin symbols
\newcommand{\lsymb}[5]
    {#1\nomenclature[A#3]{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}}
% Greek symbols
\newcommand{\gsymb}[5]
    {#1\nomenclature[G#3]{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}}
```

If I want to include a Latin symbol I type:

```
\lsymb{Symbol}{Explanation}{[Unit]}{}
```

The nomenclature then contains two separate lists, one for the Latin and one for the Greek symbols.

Just now I've encountered a "special" symbol, being a `c` with a bar over it (`$\bar{c}$`). I declare it as a Latin symbol expecting it to turn up next to other symbols starting with a `c`. However, it is printed at the beginning of the Latin symbols list.

How can I force `nomentbl` to place this symbol next to other symbols starting with a `c`? Can I maybe pre-pend a non-printing `c` to the `$\bar{c}$ to help`nomentbl` categorize it?

Comment: Please add a MWE.